# My ISP is holding all the bridges

Tags: bridge, orbot

The ISP has contracted a service that captures bridges@ and BridgeDB.
Meek works but the connection is very slow (60~100 kbps).
How do I get obfs4 bridges that they cannot capture?

Comment: Hi, do you have proof of this contract?

Comment: Or any reason at all to believe that's the case?

Comment: I know they were looking for bridges to block. I do not know how they managed to stop everything I can get in BridgeDB and bridge@.

Comment: Probably by blocking traffic that cannot be categorised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bridges that are not listed in BridgeDB are distributed manually.

As such you'd need to know someone or some organisation running such a bridge and contact them to request usage of it and obviously they'd have to actually trust you (i.e. that you weren't trying to find out the bridge address to censor it).

I find it unlikely your ISP has such a contract (there are easier paths to take and I doubt you've tested every bridge in bridgedb), but I'd love to know more if you have more information on that.

Comment: It's hard to find a bridge that works. When encounter is an obfs4 that only works for a few hours.
The ISP team grew. They may be paying new people to block the bridges.

Comment: Then an unlisted bridge would also be discovered and blocked by the same process?

Comment: Old bridges obfs4 worked months. New obfs4 bridges work 3 to 4 days.

Comment: It is increasingly difficult to find a bridge that works. I believe they are sweeping BridgeDB and blocking bridges.

Comment: Not listed obfs4 bridge may be the solution.

Comment: The delay in stopping old bridges can mean a longer delay to find in BridgeDB and block.

Comment: If you've used known bridges in the past and they're actively looking for and blocking bridges, then it's possible they'd see you using some unknown protocol and block it because it's unrecognised. Pluggable transports defeat DPI, not people actively looking at your connections, that's a much harder problem to defeat.

Comment: I believe that blocking is not in the unknown protocol, but in bridges that they find somewhere.

Comment: If they block unknown protocol. Why do some bridges take much longer to be blocked? This gives me reason to believe that they captured the address of bridges somewhere (obviously they are bridges listed).

Comment: If bridges consistently stop working a few days after you start using them it seems plausible the place they're getting the bridge addresses is you.

Comment: how can i solve this problem? .I have already used other networks where the connection is not censoring to get BridgeDB bridges, but the bridges do not work on my ISP.

Comment: Meek works and is difficult to censor.